# Boolean return type confusion

Tags: return, boolean

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    return new Integer(id).equals(((Person)obj).getId());
```

As far as i know boolean return "true" or "false" how can i use this type for this code?

Comment: You are returning the return value of `Integer.equals`, which also returns a `boolean`, doesn't it? That aside, this is a strange implementation of `equals`...

Comment: Without seeing more of the code it's difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  The 'new' keyword in the return statement doesn't look right.

Comment: @Ezra: the `new` is used to create the `Integer` instance: `new Integer(id)`